# Parse server rejecting session authentication after renewing certificates and restarting

Tags: ios, mongodb, amazon-ec2, parse-platform

I have an app running Parse server on AWS as the backend.  It has crashed because the mongoDB appears to have stopped connecting with Parse at 127.0.0.1 but I am not sure how that happened since I didn't make any code changes.  What I did do was try and update a certifiact using bncert tool.

I have to manually go in every 3 months or so to renew the certificates using `sudo /opt/bitnami/bncert-tool` where I then enter in my servername and email address.  I just performed this perodic maintenance and restarted my server.  This appears to have broken something in the parse connection to the mongoDB though.  When I go to my parse dashboard it pulls up an error log that suggests something has been deprecated for how mongoDB connects to parse?  Can someone provide any guidance as to how to fix this or how to figure out what could be going wrong?  Some things I see in the log are `errorLabels: [ 'TransientTransactionError' ]` and

The log has the error:

```
2020-05-24T01:37:49.746Z - Uncaught internal server error. { MongoNetworkError: failed to connect to server [127.0.0.1:27017] on first connect [MongoNetworkError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017]
    at Pool.<anonymous> (/opt/bitnami/apps/parse/htdocs/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/topologies/server.js:564:11)
    at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
    at Pool.emit (events.js:211:7)
    at Connection.<anonymous> (/opt/bitnami/apps/parse/htdocs/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/pool.js:317:12)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:317:30)
    at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
    at Connection.emit (events.js:214:7)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/opt/bitnami/apps/parse/htdocs/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/connection.js:246:50)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:315:30)
    at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
  name: 'MongoNetworkError',
  errorLabels: [ 'TransientTransactionError' ],
  [Symbol(mongoErrorContextSymbol)]: {} } MongoNetworkError: failed to connect to server [127.0.0.1:27017] on first connect [MongoNetworkError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017]
    at Pool.<anonymous> (/opt/bitnami/apps/parse/htdocs/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/topologies/server.js:564:11)
    at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
    at Pool.emit (events.js:211:7)
    at Connection.<anonymous> (/opt/bitnami/apps/parse/htdocs/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/pool.js:317:12)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:317:30)
    at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
    at Connection.emit (events.js:214:7)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/opt/bitnami/apps/parse/htdocs/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/connection.js:246:50)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:315:30)
    at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
2020-05-24T01:37:38.156Z - error getting auth for sessionToken
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out...  but posting here in case someone runs into the same error.  I noticed that when I logged on to my bitami ubuntu instance with parse there was a message that a system restart was required.  I also noticed that that the letsencrypt tool had an updated version. I restarted the ubuntu instance, stopped my apache server with `sudo service apache2 stop`, reran the lets encrypt certificate tool with `sudo /opt/bitnami/bncert-tool` and then restarted my parse server.js.  When I did that everything started working again!